# Поддерживается ли jquery и ajax на мобильных браузерах?

Tags: jquery, mobile, ajax

Поддерживается ли jquery и ajax на мобильных браузерах? Есть ли отличия между стандартным JS кодом(работы с ajax) и т.д.?

Comment: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть версия jquery для мобильных устройств. Там оптимизация по производительности, адаптация под экран и поддержка сенсорных устройств. http://jquerymobile.com/

Есть некоторые отличия в коде. Например, $(document).ready() уже занят под свои нужды :) и поэтому скрипты, которые должны выполняться по загрузке страницы, нужно вставлять по-другому:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
    $('.ui-loader').hide();
    // и понеслось!
});
```

Не так работает анимация. То, что плавно движется на десктопе, на планшете рисуется дёрганно. Либо планшет не успевает, либо специально понижено количество кадров анимации.

Comment: jquery-mobile это скорее  jquery-ui для мобильников, она зависит от jquery .